# Error con data_mapper y json gems

Tags: json, ruby

Gem::ConflictError: Unable to activate dm-serializer-1.2.2, because json-2.0.2 conflicts with json (~> 1.6)

```
gem list --local


*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actioncable (5.1.0)
actionmailer (5.1.0)
actionpack (5.1.0)
actionview (5.1.0)
activejob (5.1.0)
activemodel (5.1.0)
activerecord (5.1.0)
activesupport (5.1.0)
addressable (2.5.1)
arel (8.0.0)
bcrypt (3.1.11)
bcrypt-ruby (3.1.5)
bigdecimal (default: 1.3.0)
builder (3.2.3)
bundler (1.14.6)
concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
daemons (1.2.4)
data_mapper (1.2.0)
data_objects (0.10.17)
datamapper-dm-core (0.10.1)
did_you_mean (1.1.0)
dm-aggregates (1.2.0)
dm-constraints (1.2.0)
dm-core (1.2.1)
dm-do-adapter (1.2.0)
dm-migrations (1.2.0)
dm-serializer (1.2.2)
dm-sqlite-adapter (1.2.0)
dm-timestamps (1.2.0)
dm-transactions (1.2.0)
dm-types (1.2.2)
dm-validations (1.2.0)
do_sqlite3 (0.10.17)
erubi (1.6.0)
eventmachine (1.2.3)
extlib (0.9.16)
fastercsv (1.5.5)
globalid (0.4.0)
i18n (0.8.1)
io-console (default: 0.4.6)
json (default: 2.0.2)
json_pure (2.1.0, 1.8.6)
loofah (2.0.3)
mail (2.6.5)
method_source (0.8.2)
mime-types (3.1)
mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
minitest (5.10.1)
multi_json (1.12.1)
mustermann (1.0.0)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
nio4r (2.0.0)
nokogiri (1.7.2)
openssl (default: 2.0.2)
power_assert (0.4.1)
psych (default: 2.2.2)
public_suffix (2.0.5)
rack (2.0.2, 1.6.5)
rack-protection (2.0.0, 1.5.3)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails (5.1.0)
rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
railties (5.1.0)
rake (12.0.0)
rdoc (default: 5.0.0)
shotgun (0.9.2)
sinatra (2.0.0, 1.4.8)
slim (3.0.7)
sprockets (3.7.1)
sprockets-rails (3.2.0)
stringex (1.5.1)
temple (0.7.7)
test-unit (3.2.3)
thin (1.7.0)
thor (0.19.4)
thread_safe (0.3.6)
tilt (2.0.7)
tzinfo (1.2.3)
uuidtools (2.1.5)
websocket-driver (0.6.5)
websocket-extensions (0.1.2)
xmlrpc (0.2.1)
```

Cómo puedo resolver este problema?

Uso Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Anteriormente Instale data_mapper y me devolvió error de sinatra con la mmisma característica, actualicé con gem sinatra update y funcionaba en otro proyecto si data_mapper. Cuando quise utilizar el mismo devolvió el error actual con JSON.

Comment: ¿Que hiciste para que sucediera eso? ¿cual es tu `Gemfile.lock`? mas info por favor

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Sinatra estás utilizando?

Comment: Soy nuevo usando ruby, no encuentro Gemfile.lock.

Comment: sinatra (2.0.0, 1.4.8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer la versión 2.0.0 de Sinatra no funciona correctamente con DataMapper, puedes ver el reporte del problema [aquí](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/1294).

Por lo tanto, puedes intentar utilizando la versión 1.4.8 en lugar de la 2.0.0; para hacerlo tienes dos opciones:

#### 1. Utilizar [bundler](http://bundler.io/).

Bundler te permite administrar las gemas (con versiones específicas) que utilizarás a través de un `Gemfile` (más información [aquí](http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/development/bundler)), en el cual puedes especificar las versiones que utilizarás en tu proyecto; en tu caso utilizarías la versión 1.4.8 de Sinatra:

```
gem "sinatra", "~> 1.4.8"
```

Una vez que generas tu `Gemfile` y ejecutas el comando `bundle install` se generará el archivo `Gemfile.lock`, el cual contiene la información de todas las gemas utilizadas en tu proyecto junto con sus dependencias.

#### 2. Eliminar la versión 2.0.0.

Al eliminar esta versión de Sinatra, únicamente tendrás disponible la versión 1.4.8, por lo que no tendrás el problema descrito; para hacerlo ejecuta el siguiente comando:

```
$ gem uninstall sinatra --version 2.0.0
```

Te recomiendo ampliamente intentar con la primera opción (i.e. utilizar **Bundler**), ya que te dará la libertad de instalar diferentes versiones de gemas para diferentes proyectos sin tener afectaciones entre ellos.

---

#### Cómo utilizar *Bundler* con un archivo [`Gemfile`](http://bundler.io/v1.0/sinatra.html)

Supongamos que tu aplicación se llama `MiApp`, se encuentra en `mi_app/app.rb` y tiene el siguiente código:

```
require 'sinatra'

class MiApp < Sinatra::Base
  get "/" do
    "Hola mundo!"
  end
end
```

1. Crea un archivo `Gemfile`, en el directorio raíz de tu aplicación, con el siguiente contenido:

   ```
   source "https://rubygems.org"

   gem 'sinatra',           '1.4.8'
   gem 'data_mapper',       '1.2.0'
   gem 'dm-sqlite-adapter', '1.2.0'
   gem 'json',              '~>1.6'
   gem 'thin',              '1.7.0'
   gem 'slim',              '3.0.8'
   gem 'shotgun',           '0.9.2'
   ```
2. Crea un archivo `configu.ru`, también en el directorio raíz de tu aplicación, con el siguiente contenido:

   ```
   require 'rubygems'
   require 'bundler'

   Bundler.require

   require './app'
   run MiApp
   ```

   Donde `app` se refiere al nombre de tu archivo (i.e. `app.rb`) y `MiApp` al nombre de tu clase dentro de ese archivo.
3. Ejecuta `shotgun` utilizando `bundle exec` (para utilizar la versión de `rake` adecuada):

   ```
   $ bundle exec shotgun
   ```

Con esta configuración garantizas que tu aplicación utilice las gemas y versiones indicadas en el `Gemfile`, independientemente de las versiones que tengas instaladas en tu sistema.

Comment: `# frozen_string_literal: true
source "https://rubygems.org"
# gem "rails"
gem "sinatra", "~> 1.4.8"
gem "json", "~> 1.6" ` Este sería mi Gemfile @Gerry

Comment: Sigue generando el mismo error al correr la aplicación.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar tu archivo `Gemfile.lock`?

Comment: `GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    json (1.8.6)
    mustermann (1.0.0)
    rack (2.0.3)
    rack-protection (2.0.0.rc2)
      rack
    sinatra (2.0.0.rc2)
      mustermann (= 1.0.0)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-protection (= 2.0.0.rc2)
      tilt (~> 2.0)
    tilt (2.0.7)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  json (~> 1.6)
  sinatra (= 2.0.0.rc2)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.15.0`

Comment: Le agregué sinatra en la version 1.4.8 y no funcionó, le puse ahora la version 2.0.0.rc2 y tampoco. Igual que json que probé agregandole la versión ~>1.6.

Comment: Cuando ultizo sinatra en su version 1.4.8 me genera conflicto entre sinatra y rack. Al bajar la version de rack para que funcione sinatra me genera error specmissing

Comment: @Nicoo1991 Me parece que tu `Gemfile` está incompleto, pues no menciona la gema `data_mapper`; además de esa gema, ¿estás utilizando otras gemas que no hayas puesto en el `Gemfile`? Genera tu `Gemfile` con todas las gemas que necesitas con las versiones que necesitas y ejecuta `bundle install` nuevamente. Muestra el error que te salga y el `Gemfile.lock` resultante.

Comment: Todavia no entiendo como funciona el Gemfile. Yo utilizo shotgun para correr el servidor. Ejecuto bundle install y luego corro normal?

Comment: `# frozen_string_literal: true
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'sinatra', '1.4.8'
gem 'data_mapper', '1.2.0'
gem 'dm-sqlite-adapter', '1.2.0'
gem 'json', '~>1.6'
gem 'thin', '1.7.0'
gem 'slim', '3.0.8'
gem 'shotgun', '0.9.2'

# gem "rails"`

Comment: @Nicoo1991 Me parece que aún no tenías la configuración completa, checa la respuesta actualizada para configurar tu aplicación correctamente utilizando un `Gemfile`.

Comment: Perfecto Gerry, muchas gracias, Entendí como funciona para futuros proyectos el Gemfile. Saludos cordiales desde Argentina!

Comment: @Nicoo1991Saludos y suerte!